# how to fetch last data on a range that not empty

Tags: excel

I need formula how to get last value of a range in column of my data. Here is my formula to fetch it, but unfortunately failed because the cell is contain formula, not really empty.

```
=OFFSET(J3;MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(J3:J12));ROW(J3:J12);0))-ROW(J3);0)
(CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)
```

I hope to have some help from you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the last number in column J then,

```
=INDEX(J:J, MATCH(1e99, J:J))
```

If you are looking for the last text in column J then,

```
=INDEX(J:J, MATCH("zzz", J:J))
```

If you are unclear on whether it is text or a number you are seeking,

```
=INDEX(J:J, MAX(IFERROR(MATCH("zzz", J:J), 0), IFERROR(MATCH(1e99, J:J), 0)))
```

Comment: Well, thanks jeeped, really charming magician of u, although i dont understand, but it work now your first formula, that can fetch last number data in column j. what is the logic using 1e99? :)

Comment: 1e99 is a different way of expressing 1 with 99 zeroes. By looking for a number that will never be found you end up with the last number in the list.